# Search Engine Result Page Url includes Search Value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search

I am trying to create a new language translator engine (only two language available a<->b) its just to learn PHP & Mysql etc. a little bit better. Now I have a search form where a user can enter a value and a php code which check if that word is available to give the result in an antoher fix language. But a user enter a value  ex. "food" and submit it then the url should look like that

https://domain.com/search/food

How is it possible to get a permalink without using a CMS.  I only want to do all as static page and PHP, MYSQL AND JS nothing more if possible

I see that already on a few pages but not sure how to do that and hope you could give me only a few advices.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to store a file for every single possible word, this isn't possible with straight PHP, you will have to leverage your server's functionality.
Assuming you are using Apache, check the documentation for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

But, you could also simply use URL parameters, which is easier and will act pretty much the same in practice. e.g.:

`https://domain.com/search.php?term=food`

PHP:

```
$_GET['term']   // => "food"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I read taht if I use get, that get is easier to hack so I should use post. And I already thought about to save all links in a DB so add a a value to my url so it looks like that -> https://domain.com/search/food do you have another idea

Comment: ... my idea was that if I add a new word or sentences to my dictionary and a user enter that word (on domain.com/ is the search form)that he will forwardedto a new page with its translations  but the result page url should look like   domain.com/search/food

Comment: *>the result page url should look like domain.com/search/food*   I already answered that question and provided you with a workaround, you can't do what you want to do with PHP only. If you really want to do it the `/search/food` way and not `/search.php?term=food`, then you will have to inform what kind of server you are using.

Comment: *>I read taht if I use get, that get is easier to hack so I should use post*  You shouldn't transmit sensitive information using a GET request, that's all, but using GET for search queries is actually the most common way to do it. As long as you use a mechanism like PDO or mysqli to access your database you will not have security problems.